# SVG extracted using `svg-extract` looks nothing like the original SVG

Tags: latex3, svg

Here's my SVG drawing:

[image]

I include it in my LaTeX document using the `svg` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
    \includesvg{idea.svg}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

Then I use the `svg-extract` package to extract it out into a PDF including the rendered LaTeX math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[extractformat=pdf]{svg-extract}

\begin{document}
    \includesvg[keepaspectratio]{idea.svg}
\end{document}
```

I run `latexmk --shell-escape idea.tex` and the resulting PDF is as follows:

[image]

It looks like the text has been moved to accomodate some smaller bounding box than that which the SVG originally intended.

How can I prevent this behavior and get back the SVG as it looked in the original PDF?

## SVG file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="297mm"
   height="210mm"
   viewBox="0 0 297 210"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.2.2 (732a01da63, 2022-12-09)"
   sodipodi:docname="idea.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#000000"
     borderopacity="0.25"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.0000001"
     inkscape:cx="324.74999"
     inkscape:cy="230.74999"
     inkscape:window-width="3200"
     inkscape:window-height="1721"
     inkscape:window-x="5591"
     inkscape:window-y="-9"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect1048"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect14718"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient12496"
       inkscape:swatch="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#ededed;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop12494" />
    </linearGradient>
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect12378"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect12301"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect12291"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect12281"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect7434"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect7282"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient6490"
       inkscape:swatch="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop6488" />
    </linearGradient>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto-start-reverse"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1"
       markerWidth="6.0609999"
       markerHeight="10.011125"
       viewBox="0 0 4.0606602 6.7071068"
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       inkscape:collect="always"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:context-stroke;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt"
         d="M 3,-3 0,0 3,3"
         id="path5057"
         transform="rotate(180,0.125,0)"
         sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
    </marker>
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient12496"
       id="linearGradient12498"
       x1="182.39424"
       y1="65.837943"
       x2="245.46962"
       y2="65.837943"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(0.5628514,0,0,1.2624362,65.725835,1.6300776)" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect14718-0"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect14718-0-5"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="bspline"
       id="path-effect14718-0-5-7"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       weight="33.333333"
       steps="2"
       helper_size="0"
       apply_no_weight="true"
       apply_with_weight="true"
       only_selected="false" />
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.586;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow1)"
       d="M 71.590594,50.454786 V 131.46511"
       id="path245" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.586;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow1)"
       d="M 71.590594,131.46511 H 181.93108"
       id="path1275" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:3.175px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="186.05757"
       y="132.93013"
       id="text10557-1-0"><tspan
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.93889px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Italic';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none"
         x="186.05757"
         y="132.93013"
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan1108">$t$</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:3.175px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="51.640903"
       y="45.129822"
       id="text10557-1-0-5"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.93889px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Italic';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none"
         x="51.640903"
         y="45.129822"
         id="tspan10559-9-2-3">$\int{x}$</tspan></text>
    <rect
       style="fill:url(#linearGradient12498);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000101;stroke-width:0.421474;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:0.550725"
       id="rect12492"
       width="35.220638"
       height="32.770851"
       x="168.5274"
       y="68.36087" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="171.8385"
       y="74.420906"
       id="text13082"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan13080"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="171.8385"
         y="74.420906">Legend</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="181.14133"
       y="80.155449"
       id="text13082-2"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan13080-2"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="181.14133"
         y="80.155449">$p_{max}$</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="181.14133"
       y="85.640045"
       id="text13082-2-3"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan13080-2-7"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="181.14133"
         y="85.640045">$p_{tgt}$</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="181.14133"
       y="90.595474"
       id="text13082-2-3-4"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="181.14133"
         y="90.595474"
         id="tspan17322">$p_{min}$</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="181.14133"
       y="96.14344"
       id="text13082-2-3-4-3"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.165;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="181.14133"
         y="96.14344"
         id="tspan17322-2">Constraint</tspan></text>
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#ff0303;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 172.30655,79.308188 c 0,0 7.37439,0 7.37439,0"
       id="path14716"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect14718"
       inkscape:original-d="m 172.30655,79.308188 h 7.37439" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.946176;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 172.30655,84.513643 c 0,0 7.37439,0 7.37439,0"
       id="path14716-5"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect14718-0"
       inkscape:original-d="m 172.30655,84.513643 h 7.37439" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#03d000;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 172.30655,89.719098 c 0,0 7.37439,0 7.37439,0"
       id="path14716-5-0"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect14718-0-5"
       inkscape:original-d="m 172.30655,89.719098 h 7.37439" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#1100d0;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:3.5;stroke-dasharray:1, 0.5;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 172.30655,95.235799 c 0,0 7.37439,0 7.37439,0"
       id="path14716-5-0-2"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect14718-0-5-7"
       inkscape:original-d="m 172.30655,95.235799 h 7.37439" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#1100d0;stroke-width:0.600001;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:3.5"
       d="M 84.005205,121.44375 C 91.633969,104.68692 99.262789,87.929975 111.76463,76.692785 124.26648,65.455595 141.64044,59.738558 159.01458,54.02146"
       id="path1046"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect1048"
       inkscape:original-d="m 84.005205,121.44375 c 7.629083,-16.75668 15.257904,-33.513629 22.886455,-50.270837 17.37492,-5.717 34.74888,-11.434037 52.12292,-17.151453" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You might want to make the svg available somewhere.

Comment: @daleif Sure, please see edit to my original post for SVG code

Comment: I can partially confirm the issue. Nevertheless, this is caused by producing DVI output in the first place, which causes Inkscape to create an EPS file instead of a PDF. Obviously, there is something messed in this processing chain but I do not have time to investigate the whole thing. Is there any reason why you don't output PDF directly?

If this is not the case `latexmk --shell-escape -pdf idea.tex` gives the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a PDF that is cropped to the size of the included SVG, use the `standalone` document class instead of `article` ([PDF output](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/texsx-678479.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
    \includesvg{idea.svg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, you were right. `standalone` was what I needed. My bad.

Comment: It depends. If the graphic should both be included in a larger document and *additionally* be created as a standalone file, package `svg-extract` is the right approach. Just use `latexmk --shell-escape -pdf idea.tex`